# Android Home Automation development necessary to take care

Tags: android, wear-os, home-automation

i was working on android home automation app , basic things to take care while doing this user based app like , i should sync data with server on i should keep data in local, please give me links of libraries if some one worked . help me to build this product .

Answer (score 1):

Use firbase database provided by google its way easier to handle data syncronization and offline maintainance.[doc link here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/)

also a youtube link if you have no idea how firebase works [video tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B1rlT5KQ0yE)